# How to generate and write all Unicode characters in Python?

Tags: python, unicode

I have tried different methods to write all the possible Unicode characters into a file but it gives me an error for the range 55297-57344. Which encoding supports this range? `UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 55297-57344: surrogates not allowed`

```
bb=""
for b in range(0, 1114111):
    bb+=chr(b)

with open('allcharacters', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(bb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Code points U+D800 through U+DFFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+D800_to_U+DFFF) are contained in the various ["Surrogates" Unicode blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates). They result when UTF-16 text containing text in the Supplementary Multilingual Planes is (mis)decoded as UCS-2; they should never result in normal operation, and should not be treated as characters.

Comment: is there a way to filter out the blank Unicode characters?

Comment: Unassigned characters have a category of "Cn". Surrogates are "Cs".